# Add space between trailer and %s only if trailer exists

Tags: git

I'm trying to create a format to show something like this:

[abbreviated-hash] [issue-number] [subject]

The issue number is a trailer that has the format "Issue: [issue-key]". But sometimes a commit message does not have this information.

I wrote the following format:

`git log --format='%h %(trailers:key=Issue,valueonly,separator=%x2C) %s'`

In the cases when the issue number is not present on commit messages, this format adds two spaces between the hash abbreviation and the subject.

How can I put this format in a way that the space between the subject and the issue number occurs only when the issue number is present?

Here is an example of my log with that format:

[image: Formated log]

And here is the original commit messages:

[image: Original commit messages]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the identical effect by putting a space before the trailer if and only if the trailer is present, a bit farther along in the `PRETTY FORMATS` section (that title really needs an exclamation mark, no?), there's

> If you add a + (plus sign) after % of a placeholder, a line-feed is
>      inserted immediately before the expansion if and only if the
>      placeholder expands to a non-empty string.
>
> If you add a - (minus sign) after % of a placeholder, all consecutive
>      line-feeds immediately preceding the expansion are deleted if and only
>      if the placeholder expands to an empty string.
>
> If you add a  (space) after % of a placeholder, a space is inserted
>      immediately before the expansion if and only if the placeholder expands
>      to a non-empty string.

so use e.g.

```
pretty=format:'%h% (trailers:key=Issue,valueonly,separator=%x2C)% s'
```

to put space separators only in front of fields that have something worth separating.

Comment: I totally agree with the exclamation mark suggestion! I had read the pretty formats section but I didn't saw that part of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe the output into sed to remove the extra space

```
git log --format='%h %(trailers:key=Issue,valueonly,separator=%x2C) %s' | sed -E 's/^([a-f0-9]{10}  /\1 /'


-E: Regular expression  
^: Start of line  
[a-f0-9]{10}: match up to first 10 hex numbers  
\1 :Paste hex match from beginning of line
```